# PHP Array Blank Select options

Tags: php, mysql, select

Im currently working on a University project to create a working e-commerce site using PHP. Although I have been using HTML for many years PHP is still a foreign language. I am still learning the very basics. I find the best way for me learning is to have a fiddle.

I have a problem with a HTML select drop-down which is collecting its values from a PHP array, which is collected through a MySQL database. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//Connect to Session
include "conn.php";

//Retrieve Header
include "header.php";

//Query
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $product_id = $_GET['id'];
    $q="SELECT ProductName,img,ProductID,Description,p_spec1,p_spec2,p_spec3,p_spec4,p_spec5,Price,size_1,size_2,size_3,size_4,size_5 FROM Products 
                    WHERE ProductID=$product_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);

//Display
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        //DO NOT SHOW BLANK ARRAYS METHOD ONE
        $row = array_filter($row);              
        echo "<div>
        <p><b>Name:</b> $row[0]</p>

        <p><img src=".$row[1]."></p>

        <p><b>Product Code: </b>$row[2]</p>

        <p><b><u>Product Description:</b></u></p>
        <p>$row[3]</p>

        <p><b><u>Product Spec:</b></u> <li>$row[4]</li><li>$row[5]</li><li>$row[6]</li><li>$row[7]</li><li>$row[8]</li></p>

        <p><b>Price:</b> &#163;$row[9]</p>

        <p><b>Quantity:</b>
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p><b>Size:</b>
            <select>
                <option>$row[10]</option>
                <option>$row[11]</option>
                <option>$row[12]</option>
                <option>$row[13]</option>
                <option>$row[14]</option>
            </select>   
        </p>
        </div>";
    }
    else {
        echo $row="";
    }

//Add Item to basket
    echo "<div><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&product=$product_id\">
                        Add to Bag</a></div>";
}

//Retrieve Footer
include "footer.php";
?>
```

As you've probably already worked out... I believe the problem to be down to the fact that I am declaring five options. Is there a way for me to declare one and if the others hold values within the database they are added as an option?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: how much option will come in select box?

Comment: Apologies for not stating this...

There are a total of 5 possible options for the Sizes ($row10 to $row14)

Comment: Does your $row contains any Value?? I think you are confusing between mysql_query() with mysqli_query();

Comment: Why dont you use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to loop through the values. If you are sure of the starting value to be $row[10] then you can manage with a for loop. Something of the sort below.

```
for ($i=10;i<lenght_of_array;i++)
{
    <option>$row[i]</option>
}
```

Comment: That's Fantastic. Cheers for your help everyone! All working, sure ill be around again at some point with more questions. Cheers – Matt Kidd just now edit

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Connect to Session
    include "conn.php";

    //Retrieve Header
    include "header.php";

    //Query
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $product_id = $_GET['id'];
        $q="SELECT ProductName,img,ProductID,Description,p_spec1,p_spec2,p_spec3,p_spec4,p_spec5,Price,size_1,size_2,size_3,size_4,size_5 FROM Products 
                        WHERE ProductID=$product_id";
        $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);

    //Display
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            //DO NOT SHOW BLANK ARRAYS METHOD ONE
            $row = array_filter($row);     

         $option ='';
for($i=10;$i<15;$i++){
    if(isset($row[$i]) && !empty($row[$i])){
        $option.='<option>'".$row[10]."'</option>';
    }


            echo "<div>
            <p><b>Name:</b> $row[0]</p>

            <p><img src=".$row[1]."></p>

            <p><b>Product Code: </b>$row[2]</p>

            <p><b><u>Product Description:</b></u></p>
            <p>$row[3]</p>

            <p><b><u>Product Spec:</b></u> <li>$row[4]</li><li>$row[5]</li><li>$row[6]</li><li>$row[7]</li><li>$row[8]</li></p>

            <p><b>Price:</b> &#163;$row[9]</p>

            <p><b>Quantity:</b>
                <select>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p><b>Size:</b>
                <select>".$option."
                </select>   
            </p>
            </div>";
        }
        else {
            echo $row="";
        }

    //Add Item to basket
        echo "<div><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&product=$product_id\">
                            Add to Bag</a></div>";
    }

    //Retrieve Footer
    include "footer.php";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is you problem exactly? If you won't always have values within the $row[10] - $row[14] fields then you should do a loop.

```
   echo "<div>
        <p><b>Name:</b>".$row[0]."</p>

        <p><img src='".$row[1]."'></p>

        <p><b>Product Code: </b>".$row[2]."</p>

        <p><b><u>Product Description:</b></u></p>
        <p>".$row[3]."</p>

        //Do this up to select box and then 

            <select>";

for($i=10;$i<15;$i++) {
  if($row[$i]!='')
  echo "<option>".$row[$i]."</option>";
}

    echo"</select>   
        </p>
        </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sizes are null otherwise you can check them before echoing them:

```
if (!is_null($row10)) {
    echo "<option>" . $row10 . "</option>";
}
```